# definition of closure using convergence vs topological definition

Tags: general-topology, analysis, convergence-divergence

In real analysis, we learned that $x \in cl(A)$ iff $\exists$ a sequence $x_n \to x$ with $x_n \in A$.

I have to show that in general this statement is not true, so I was trying to use the co-countable where the open sets are those whose complement is countable. Is the following argument sound?

Let $X = \mathbb{R}, A = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{p\}$, where $X$ is equipped with the co-countable topology. Clearly $p$ is in the $cl(A)$, which means if the analytic definition of closure holds, we can find a sequence $x_n \to p$ with $x_n \in A$. In a topological space, we have $x_n \to p$ if $\forall U \in \tau_X$ with $p \in U$, we can find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n \in U$ for $n \geq N$. Consider $U = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{x_n | x_n \neq p\}$, since the sequence $x_n$ is countable, $U \in \tau_X$. Since by construction $p \in U$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $x_n \in U$ for $n \geq N$. However, all $x_n \neq p$ are not in $U$, so $x_n = p$ for $n \geq N$ and is eventually constant. But this is a contradiction, since $p \not \in A$, there exist $x_n \not \in A$.

Comment: I get what you are trying to do, and your argument works. I would just change the end a little so that there is no confusion over dummy variables. Maybe a change along the lines of... "Say $n \geqslant N$. Then $x_n \neq p$ as $x_n \in A$. However, by choice of $N$ we have $x_n \in U =\left( \mathbb{R} \backslash \{x_k : k \in \mathbb{N} \}\right) \cup \{p\} $, from which it follows that $x_n = p$. We thus arrive at the contradiction $p \neq x_n = p$."

Comment: Yes, the proof seems fine. The analytic definition holds in metric spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I'd split the argument in two:

1 .If $x_n \rightarrow x$ in the co-countable topology ,then form some $N$, $\forall n \ge N$ $x_n =x$.
THe idea of your argument is OK, I also wrote it doen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2147651/4280)

So if $x_n \in A \setminus \{p\}$ it cannot converge to $p$ at all. Becuause that woukld imply that almost all $X_n$ are $p$, which cannot be.